# Core Data and Image Caching

Tags: ios

While I have been working with iOS apps for some time now, I am totally new to core data. So, just have a simple question.

Can images be cached and stored in core data?

I could not find any sample app for caching images into core data. It would be of great help if someone can share me links for image caching in core data in case this is possible.

[P.S I know image caching. So, not looking for links or samples for only image caching. Please share info on image caching with core data]

Comment: I think this can already be found on stackoverflow : [Storing images in core data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158286/storing-images-in-core-data?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data - Storing Images (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090028/core-data-storing-images-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2012/03/core-data-image-caching/) article.

But IMO it's better to just store imageURLs in your Core Data database and cache them with `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` (AFNetworking awesomeness).

Answer (score -1):

Check one of the below tutorials:

- [Core Data Image Caching](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2012/03/core-data-image-caching/)
- [File System vs Core Data: the image cache test](http://biasedbit.com/filesystem-vs-coredata-image-cache/)
- [USING COREDATA TO CACHE AND DISPLAY IMAGES VIA INSTAGRAM](http://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/4151/)

Comment: You should avoid just linking without explanations, if the link goes up in smoke, its of no help