# QLPreviewController with Core Data as data source

Tags: ios, core-data, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to preview common files by using `QLPreviewController`. The files I have stored are stored in `Core Data`. The problem is that `QLPreviewController` asks for a URL to the file, which I don't have. Is there a way of combining `QLPreviewController` with `Core Data`? The files I have are stored in the database itself, but with `Allow external storage` checked, so some files might be stored separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to store the path of binary data in core data.

This link explains well.

[Storing images in Core Data or as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158286/storing-images-in-core-data-or-as-file)

Hope it is helpful.